# whatsapp bot without third party like Twilio or web driver

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, whatsapp

I'm planning to integrate a simple chatbot to WhatsApp which I build using fastapi and python. My goal is to send/receive messages to users using the WhatsApp Api. I want to know how can I connect WhatsApp Api without using a web driver or third party?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but you need to gain access to the WhatsApp business platform. Once you have access, you can use the [WhatsApp Cloud API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/) which is a HTTP API. Using webhooks you can receive conversations.

For example, to send a message:

```
curl -i -X POST \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/FROM_PHONE_NUMBER_ID/messages \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{ "messaging_product": "whatsapp", "to": "TO_PHONE_NUMBER", "type": "template", "template": { "name": "hello_world", "language": { "code": "en_US" } } }'
```

However note that at this time access is limited, e.g. they do not allow application development for other clients. And it is not free after the first 1000 conversations per month, they charge for each conversation.

Comment: Thank you, I want to us is it possible to send me sample of the -X POST to get all message conversation

Comment: The only way to receive messages is using a webhook (a URL on your server where WhatsApp sends a notification to when you receive a message). There is no method to receive all messages using an HTTP request.

Comment: I meant is there an http request to retrieve all conversation for a particular phone number or i have to store data conversation to database for each request based on the phone number as ID

Comment: Yeah you have to store it indeed. You cannot retrieve all conversations for a phone number, the only way to receive them is by using the webhook (which is called every time a new message is received by your app). So you need to store them by yourself indeed.